# No details on "Event" SVG JS

Tags: typescript, svg, svg.js

I'm trying to get drag drop to work.

```
rect.on("dragend.namespace", e => {
    const { handler, box } = e.detail;
    e.preventDefault()
          
    handler.move(box.x - (box.x % 50), box.y - (box.y % 50))
})
```

From the docs. But I'm getting

> Property 'detail' does not exist on type 'Event'.ts(2339)
> any

The properties e does have are from an Event defined in node_modules\typescript\lib, not the one in \node_modules@svgdotjs\svg.js.

Could I have configured something incorrectly? I am using Typescript.

Comment: I don't think that SVG.js change the naming of events from the standard. So either the event is just called `dragend` or you are in the process of defining a custom event (the detail property is specific for custom events).

Comment: It is indeed a custom event. The types of the libs are not 100 percent correct. So just cast them to your liking to make it work